# How can I store scraped data correctly in the item object and save each set to 1 csv file?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I got my small spider to work great. I'm getting all my data as expected. I took advantage of setting up my items.py to capture my 7 pieces of data we want. And I can write that data out to files.. BUT the issue I'm having now is I need to capture the data into 1 output file in the order that we have the items.py setup. Can't seem to figure out how to create the file if it doesn't exist(sitename and date to make it a unique file name).

This is what I have currently, but this creates 1 file for every page/url that is scraped, I want to consolidate all that into 1 file per site we scrape.

I dont like the itmDetails2 way of formatting the data, unless that is the only way, but i figured sine the dets[] is my items.py list of values that I could simply store each set in that and then write the dets[] to a csv.

What is a good example of accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I found a Python/web scraping cheat sheet and tried the examples for saving the data, but didn't work

```
https://blog.hartleybrody.com/web-scraping-cheat-sheet/

            itmDetails2 = dets['sku'] +","+ dets['description']+","+ dets['price']+","+ dets['brand']+","+ dets['compurl']+","+ dets['reviewcount']+","+ dets['reviewrating']
            
            filename = 'dsg-%s.txt' % dets['description']
            
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                for its in itmDetails2:
                    f.write(str(its))
```

This is my items.py file, since I'm capturing all or most of this date per scrape loop, how can I write each set out to the csv as a comma delimited row?

```
import scrapy

class Dsg2Item(scrapy.Item):
description = scrapy.Field()
sku = scrapy.Field()
price = scrapy.Field()
brand = scrapy.Field()
compurl = scrapy.Field()
reviewcount = scrapy.Field()
reviewrating = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: Can you post all of your code? You're missing key parts like the loop which is giving you multiple URLs to scrape.  As posted it seems as though itmDetails2 is a single string.  Also, use the csv module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using the `w` argument when opening the file. This will cause the file to be truncated to zero each time (contents deleted). In Python, the attributes are the same as the [C standard library function fopen()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/).

> `w` Truncate to zero length or create text file for writing.  The
>                stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

You should use `a+` instead, which will open the file and append contents to the end, rather than truncating the existing contents:

> `a+` Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
>                exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subse-
>                quent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
>                end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

Example:

```py
itmDetails2 = dets['sku'] +","+ dets['description']+","+ dets['price']+","+ dets['brand']+","+ dets['compurl']+","+ dets['reviewcount']+","+ dets['reviewrating']

filename = 'dsg-%s.txt' % dets['description']

localLog = open(filename,"a+")
localLog.write(itmDetails2+"\r\n")
localLog.close()
```

I'll further note, that the reason it creates a new file each time, is because you are creating your filename, based on the description. Just don't include a description if you want one filename.

Example:

```py
itmDetails2 = dets['sku'] +","+ dets['description']+","+ dets['price']+","+ dets['brand']+","+ dets['compurl']+","+ dets['reviewcount']+","+ dets['reviewrating']

localLog = open("dsg-all.txt","a+")
localLog.write(itmDetails2+"\r\n")
localLog.close()
```

Comment: the last 3 lines you provided worked for storing everything into 1 file, so the 2nd part to my original question now, my dets[] is declared at the very top of my code. Since that is a items object and im populating it during each loop, can i not call it instead of the itmDetails2? And if so, what is the syntax to do so?

Comment: As for the file name i was trying to add a unique timestamp per run so we can determine the time anything may have changes from the last run..     but this code :   now = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())  is returning a number with a decimal and i dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use csvwriter, or use the a append mode in writing a file.
there's also tinydb for local json storage